await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) does not change the database content unless page is reloded
I'm doing very basic CRUD Blazor Web App, my Create and Delete works just fine, as soon as I add or remove an item in my database the item is immediately updated on my razor page. But not when I use the update method, I tried different approaches and nothing works. I don't really understand why create and delete works just fine, but not update?
I'm calling methods with onclick - buttons. When user click "Update"/"Create"/"Delete" a form will show that ask about Id of the record you want to delete or update. Or just ask to fill in to create a new data.
Here is my "Create" method that works as it should, as soon as the user press the Add button the list with data from my database shows.
private async Task AddTrick()
{
    await dr.Create(newTrick);
    isVisibleCreate = false;
    newTrick = new Tricks();
}

Here is my Update method from my razor page:
private async Task LoadTrick()
{
    trick = await dr.GetTrickByIdAsync(idTrick);
}

private async Task UpdateTrick()
{
    await dr.Update(trick);
    isVisibleUpdate = false;
    trick = await dr.GetTrickByIdAsync(idTrick);
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}

Here are my CRUD methods from another class
public async Task Create(Tricks trick)
{
    _context.Trick.AddAsync(trick);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task Update(Tricks trick)
{
    var t = await _context.Trick.FindAsync(trick.Id);

    t.Description = trick.Description;
    t.Name = trick.Name;
    t.Length = trick.Length;
    t.Done = trick.Done;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

As requested, here are my buttons:
   <button @onclick="ShowFormUpdate">  Update </button>



   @if (isVisibleUpdate)
   {
    <div>
        <label for="idTrick">Enter Trick ID to update:</label>
        <input type="number" id="trickId" @bind="idTrick" />
        <button @onclick="LoadTrick"> Load Trick</button>
    </div>


    @if (trick != null)
    {
        <div>

            <label for="NameTrick">Enter Name of the Trick to add:</label>
            <input type="text" id="NameTrick" @bind="trick.Name" />

            <label for="NameDesc">Enter description of the Trick to add:</label>
            <input type="text" id="NameDesc" @bind="trick.Description" />

            <label for="LengthTrick">Enter length of the Trick to add:</label>
            <input type="number" id="LengthTrick" @bind="trick.Length" />

            <label for="isDone">Enter if the trick is done:</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="isDone" @bind="trick.Done" />

            <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="UpdateTrick">Update</button>
        </div>
    }

}


There's nothing in the code you've shown to point to the problem.  How are you calling the methods you've shown.  Is it different from how you call Create and Delete.  My [absolute] guess is you have an async void somewhere?

I added more code, hope that helps

OK, still no reason.  Show the buttons.

Added code for the buttons, but I honestly don't see how the problem is in that part of the project.

What type of DbContext are you using?  You should be using a DbContextFactory, by I'm guessing your using a single context and trick = await dr.GetTrickByIdAsync(idTrick); may be getting a cached object.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-9.0

You need to identify if it's a render issue, or a db issue (cache or something). When you call UpdateTrick method, can you enter in debug mode and see what's the new values of the trick after reloading it ?
And btw, when you call a method from a @onclick event, the StateHasChanged is automatically called after, so you don't need to call it in the UpdateTrick method. Here you are rendering twice the component

I know, I just hoped it would magically fix it hah, in debug mode I can see that the value changes in db without the need to relode. Just not on the website.

From your posted code I believe you missed to call:
await _context.Trick.UpdateAsync(trick);

You have AddAsync() called in your Create() method. Should include UpdateAsync() in your update method otherwise the object state changed in memory only.
public async Task Create(Tricks trick)
{
    _context.Trick.AddAsync(trick);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task Update(Tricks trick)
{
    var t = await _context.Trick.FindAsync(trick.Id);

    t.Description = trick.Description;
    t.Name = trick.Name;
    t.Length = trick.Length;
    t.Done = trick.Done;

    // You need this line
    await _context.Trick.UpdateAsync(t);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}


I tried adding _context.Trick.Update(trick); but I still have to manually relode the page to see changes. I tried using UpdateAsync() as you suggested but I only get an error

Can you try to narrow down your question to create a [mre] so we can reproduce the problem and help you find a solution? Also what is the error you got?
